# Add Dynamic variable to block

Tags: magento2

How do you display the current logged in customers name or customer ID inside a content block?

Or

How do you add dynamic variables to custom variables?

Answer (score 0):

To pass some data in block you have to use `setData()`

Exemple:

```
$data1 = "foo";
$this->getChild('child_name')->setData('item', $data1);
echo $this->getChildHtml('child_name');
```